# Fragment with four images layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-xml

I can't figure out how my layout should look like. I have a fragment. Inside it, I have scrollView (as I wish to support both orrientations), inside ScrollView I would like to have four images evenly distributed ( like this http://numberexplosion.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/square-4.gif ). But I just can't figure out a way to do it, I have tried relative, linear, tablelayouts, but can't get such view :/.

My current layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageVieww2"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageVieww3"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageVieww4"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

This layout looks nearly as I wish it to be, but the image size is only 150dp, and not filling the whole screen in some cases. My imageView sources are different, but I would like to imageViews to fill my fragment. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. I know its a heavy layout but it will solve you problem. I just used two `horizontal Linear layouts` in a `Vertical Linear Layout.` 
I placed 2 buttons in each `horizontal linear layout` with `weight 1`.

[image: Layout Vertical] [image: Layout Horizontal]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It does the work with static buttons. But I have imageViews, in which I am loading my images, and after loading the view gets distorted :/

Answer (score 0):

A fairly good solution is to use `LinearLayout` containing 2 `LinearLayouts` each containing 2 `Views`. The trick is to use `layout_width` / `layout_height` of `0dp` and `layout_weight` on children (2 `LinearLayouts` and 4 `Views`).

You may also want to try `GridLayout` (not `GridView`), which is available from Android 4.0 (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) and from 2.1 in support-library-v7.